# How to code 2 text styles in one line?

Tags: css, html

I want "p" to be lowercase, 12px Helvetica font, light, centred. I want DREAMWEAVER AND, PHOTOSHOP, INDESIGN AND, ILLUSTRATOR to be capital, bold, 12px Helvetica font, bold, centred. There needs to be a line break or line height space. How do I have 2 text styles?

My code so far:

Today's lesson is
        DREAMWEAVER AND
        PHOTOSHOP
        and also
        INDESIGN AND
        ILLUSTRATOR

Comment: please study the online resources before asking such questions on SO. You could have found this easily on Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the different words in span and style them like this:

```
<p>
Today's lesson is<br>
<span>DREAMWEAVER AND
PHOTOSHOP</span>
and also<br>
<span>INDESIGN AND
ILLUSTRATOR</span>
</p>
```

and the style

```
p{
font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
}

p span{

  display:block;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use heading codes for those texts.
Example:

```
Today's lesson is
<h1>DREAMWEAVER AND PHOTOSHOP</h1>
and also
<h1>INDESIGN AND ILLUSTRATOR</h1>
```

Then use style.css to manipulate heading 1, like:

```
h1{
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
text-align:center;
}
```

You can also manipulate paragraph:

```
p{
font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct usage of the `<h1>` element.